# Proving that $\sqrt{x^2+1}+x>0$ for all $x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, proof-explanation, radicals, hyperbolic-functions

Recently while dealing with inverse hyperbolic functions, I came across the expression
$$\sinh^{-1}x=\ln(x+\sqrt{x^2+1})$$

We know that $f(x)=\sinh^{-1}x$ is defined for all real values of $x$ since the range for $\sinh x$ is all real numbers.

But I would like to prove this by proving that $\ln(x+\sqrt{x^2+1})$ is defined for all real values. For this, clearly, $x+\sqrt{x^2+1}>0$ but how do you prove this?

I can see that for $x>0,$
$$\sqrt{x^2+1}>\sqrt{x^2}=x>0$$
$$\implies f(x)=x+\sqrt{x^2+1}>0 \text{  }[\because x>0]$$

But what about when $x<0?$ I understand that $\sqrt{x^2+1}$ will always be greater than $0$ but how do you deal with the $+x?$

Another idea I have is to consider $|x-\sqrt{x^{2}+1}|$ and use the fact that $0<|x-\sqrt{x^{2}+1}|<1$ to show that $\sqrt{x^{2}+1}$ and $x$ cannot be "too far apart" and since $\sqrt{x^{2}+1}>1$, $x+\sqrt{x^{2}+1}>0$ for all real $x$. But this method doesn't seem very robust, so I was wondering if there was a more convincing argument and less roundabout way of doing this.

PS – I may be missing some simple algebra, but am only in high school, so would appreciate it if any answers are not too convoluted.

Comment: $\sqrt {x^{2}+1} >\sqrt {x^{2}}=|x|\geq -x$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Thank you so much! This is exactly what I was missing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that the inequality is obvious when $x$ is zero or positive. It remains for us to check that $x$ is a negative number.

For any negative $x$, $|x|=-x$. Hence,
$$\sqrt{x^2 + 1} > \sqrt{x^2} = |x| = -x.$$
We then have
$$\sqrt{x^2 + 1} > - x$$
$$\sqrt{x^2 + 1} + x >0.$$

Answer (score 6):

$$(\sqrt{x^2+1}+x)(\sqrt{x^2+1}-x)=1$$
One of the factors is positive because either $x$ or $-x$ is positive, so the other factor is positive as well.

Comment: For benefit of OP - note how this follows the (familiar?) pattern $(a+b)(a-b)=a^2-b^2$ where $a$ and $b$ may be expressions involving square roots. When you first see such things they can be confusing or seem mysterious, but once understood they can come in handy.

Answer (score 0):

WLOG

$x=\cot2y, 0<2y<\pi$ using [Principal values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions#Principal_values)

$$\sqrt{x^2+1}+x=\csc2y+\cot2y=\cdots=\cot y>0$$ as $0<y<\dfrac\pi2$ and $\cos y\ne0$

Answer (score 0):

1)$x\ge 0$; the inequality is satisfied.

$2)x<0;$

Rewrite as

$\sqrt{x^2+1} - \sqrt{x^2}=$

$\dfrac {1} {\sqrt{x^2+1}+\sqrt{x^2}}>0,$ and we are done.

Answer (score 0):

1. x = 0; the inequality is satisfied 1 > 0
2. x < 0; $\sqrt{x^2+1}-x > 0;$
3. x > 0; $\sqrt{x^2 + 1}+x > 0;$